# ArangoDB AQL: Update single object in embedded array

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to update the attribute on a json document in an embedded array using AQL.  How do i update the "addressline" for "home" type address using AQL below?

### User:

```
{
name: "test",
address: [
      {"addressline": "1234 superway", type:"home"}, 
      {"addressline": "5678 superway", type:"work"}
     ]
}
```

### AQL Attempt so far

```
for u in users
   for a in u.address
     FILTER a.type='home'
       UPDATE u WITH {<What goes here to update addressline?>} in users
```

Thank you for the help.

Regards,
Anjan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this we have to work with temporary variables. We will collect the sublist in there and alter it. We choose a simple boolean filter condition to make the query better comprehensible.

First lets create a collection with a sample:

```
database = db._create('complexCollection')
database.save({ 
  "topLevelAttribute" : "a", 
  "subList" : [ 
    { 
      "attributeToAlter" : "oldValue", 
      "filterByMe" : true 
    }, 
    { 
      "attributeToAlter" : "moreOldValues", 
      "filterByMe" : true 
    }, 
    { 
      "attributeToAlter" : "unchangedValue", 
      "filterByMe" : false 
    } 
  ] 
})
```

Heres the Query which keeps the *subList* on *alteredList* to update it later:

```
FOR document in complexCollection
  LET alteredList = (
    FOR element IN document.subList 
       LET newItem = (! element.filterByMe ?
                      element :
                      MERGE(element, { attributeToAlter: "shiny New Value" }))
       RETURN newItem)
  UPDATE document WITH { subList:  alteredList } IN complexCollection
```

While the query as it is is now functional:

```
db.complexCollection.toArray()
[ 
  { 
    "_id" : "complexCollection/392671569467", 
    "_key" : "392671569467", 
    "_rev" : "392799430203", 
    "topLevelAttribute" : "a", 
    "subList" : [ 
      { 
        "filterByMe" : true, 
        "attributeToAlter" : "shiny New Value" 
      }, 
      { 
        "filterByMe" : true, 
        "attributeToAlter" : "shiny New Value" 
      }, 
      { 
        "filterByMe" : false, 
        "attributeToAlter" : "unchangedValue" 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

This query will probably be soonish a performance bottleneck, since it **modifies** all documents in the collection **regardless whether the values change or not**. Therefore we want to only *UPDATE* the documents if we really change their value. Therefore we employ a second *FOR* to test whether *subList* will be altered or not:

```
FOR document in complexCollection
  LET willUpdateDocument = (
    FOR element IN document.subList 
      FILTER element.filterByMe LIMIT 1 RETURN 1)

  FILTER LENGTH(willUpdateDocument) > 0

  LET alteredList = (
    FOR element IN document.subList 
       LET newItem = (! element.filterByMe ?
                      element :
                      MERGE(element, { attributeToAlter: "shiny New Value" }))
       RETURN newItem)

  UPDATE document WITH { subList:  alteredList } IN complexCollection
```

Comment: Thanks @dothebart! This is great! I knew that the entire sublist might have to be passed in the update/merge but was struggling with setting up that sublist. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

ArangoDB now supports subset indexes. The following query is based on [dothebart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3237176/dothebart)s answer:

```
FOR document IN complexCollection
    FILTER document.subList[*].filterByMe == true LIMIT 1
    UPDATE document WITH {
        items: (
            FOR element IN document.subList
                RETURN element.filterByMe == true
                     ? MERGE(element, { attributeToAlter: "the shiniest value"})
                     : element
        )
    } IN complexCollection
```

**Note**: Don't forget to create a `hash` index on `subList[*].filterByMe`:

```
db._collection('complexCollection')
    .ensureIndex({type:'hash',fields:['subList[*].filterByMe']});
```