# ArangoDB / AQL Update Nested Documents

Tags: arangodb, aql

Given the following document structure:

```
{
  "_key": "abc",
  "_id": "abc",
  "label": "Company ABC",
  "departments": [
    {
      "name": "Department 123",
      "id": "123"
    },
    {
      "name": "Department 456",
      "id": "456"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you tell me why the following query doesn't work? The error message is "missing document key". I found a much longer more convoluted workaround in another SO ([ArangoDB AQL: Update single object in embedded array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105660/arangodb-aql-update-single-object-in-embedded-array)) but I'm curious as to what exactly is wrong with the simpler query.

```
FOR c IN company
  FOR d in c.deparments
    FILTER d.id == “456”
    UPDATE d WITH { name: “Department 789” } IN company
RETURN d
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, I only know how to update top level attributes in ArangoDB. While I hope there are alternatives brought to my attention in the future, here are some options for your scenario.

## Update with MERGE

In this example, we update the top level `departments` attribute by rewriting the array and using `MERGE` function when our condition is hit.

```
LET company = DOCUMENT("companies/abc")

UPDATE company WITH {
  departments:
   (FOR department IN company.departments
     RETURN department.id == "456" ?
       MERGE(department, {name: "Department 789"}) : department)
} IN companies
```

## Using an alternative data model

The above example assumes department data is embedded in company documents. Consider the following:

**"companies" collection**

```
{
  "_key": "abc",
  "_id": "companies/abc",
  "label": "Company ABC"
}
```

**"departments" collection (separate docs)**

```
{
  "_key": "456",
  "_id": "departments/456",
  "company": "companies/abc",
  "name": "Department 456"
}

{
  "_key": "123",
  "_id": "departments/123",
  "company": "companies/abc",
  "name": "Department 123"
}
```

**Getting Company #ABC with Departments:**

```
LET company = DOCUMENT("companies/abc")

LET departments =
  (FOR department IN departments
    FILTER department.company == company._id
    RETURN department)

RETURN MERGE(company, {departments})
```

*Results:*

```
{
  "_id": "companies/abc",
  "_key": "abc",
  "label": "Company ABC",
  "departments": [
    {
      "_key": "456",
      "_id": "departments/456",
      "company": "companies/abc",
      "name": "Department 456"
    },
    {
      "_key": "123",
      "_id": "departments/123",
      "company": "companies/abc",
      "name": "Department 123"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Updating Department #456:**

```
LET department = DOCUMENT("departments/456")

UPDATE department WITH {name: "Department 789"} IN departments
```

Note that you'll want to add an index on the `company` attribute in the `departments` collection. You can get details on indexing here:

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/index-and-search/indexing/which-index-to-use-when/

You'll have to weigh the pros and cons of the two models.

Comment: Thank you! Your first solution is similar to my original AQL but is much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: "I hope there are alternatives brought to my attention in the future" - Have there been any updates to this topic? I have the same question and I'd like to know the best practice.