# How to replace a status in array?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have tried to modify a document by using data queries.

This works fine for a normal structure. But when query is in a array form. This doesn't seems to replace or modify the status. How can I achieve this ?

this is my array

```
 `{
  "slave_state_datasets": [
    {
    "no": 0,
    "name": "abce",
    "status": true,
    "interrupt_time": 0.2,
    "timestamp": 1,
    "dataset_input": [
      {
      "data": 8,
      "ui16_u_u2": 1,
      "ui16_u_dip_min": 1,
      "ui16_u_swell_max": 1,
       }
    ]
  }
 ]
 }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this on 3.3.3, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815102/153083) by [RienNeVaPlu͢s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650150/riennevaplu%CD%A2s)

```
for t in test
filter t._key == '516226'
let alteritem = (for s in t.slave_state_datasets
            let updateStatus = MERGE(s, {status: false})
        return updateStatus)
update t with {slave_state_datasets:alteritem} IN test
```

You assign the inner value to `alteritem`, update the `status` with `MERGE` and then update the parent document. See the linked answer for more detail on filtering arrays.